# Why are my Citizens and peasants stuck in their status?

Tags: anno-1404

I have Peasants as well as Citizens and both groups have all needs fulfilled. 
I have fast forwarded the game quite a while, but both groups refuse to rise in status. 
The advance permits on the market building are unlocked too.

**How can I make them rise their status?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the required building materials to upgrade their houses. Going from Citizens to to Patricians requires 1 Tools, 1 Wood, and 4 Stone.

Source: http://anno1404.wikia.com/wiki/Patrician#Materials

Also note some of the other things said at the link above for possible reasons why advancement has stopped:

> Common reasons the population does not advance is that the population does not have all items needed, the population is being taxed too high, or there is not the correct proportion of each class.
>   Unlike Anno 1701, you can't get far at all if your civilization is only peasants. Citizens need peasants to live, patricians need citizens and peasants to live, and so on. To determine how many houses can still ascend, click on the city's market place and look at the pyramid. For example, if it shows there are 31/31 noble houses, it means you've reached the maximum number of noble houses.

Comment: Thanks, it was the taxes in my case. Set them 1 step up and that prevented them.

Comment: well I have been playing for 3 straight days now and still cannot advance from citizen status ... this mechanic is kind of trash imo ...